# opening a file in shell scripting

Tags: file, shell, text, adventure

I have been making a text adventure in shell-script but, at one point I want it to open up a different script while it is running (so have both of them running). I have researched for about an hour and still haven't found anything.. Can you help?

Example:

```
printf "System: Now gathering power needed 1/3"
```

then open the script

Comment: You should research for _days_ at least. An hour is nothing.

Comment: What's wrong with simply running the other script: `other-script`?  Or add a path in front of it?  Or add an `&` at the end?  Are they both going to be reading from the terminal at the same time?  You might want to use `. other-script` or (in Bash) `source other-script` to read the other file as part of the current environment.  That mans basically that you run the commands in `other-script` as part of the current shell.  Etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't want to have the user have go and open it (for annoyance reasons) and well it is a script that speaks stuff so I wanted to add dialog for fun

Comment: You're already running one script.  That script can run another easily enough.  The question is, will any of the data entered in the second script be needed in the first script.  If not, then separate execution is appropriate; if so, then using the `. other-script` notation is plausible too.  If not, then simply use `other-script'.  What haven't you told us yet that makes both of these options unpalatable?

Comment: No, I will not be needing data from one to another so I will use the other-script Thank you!!

Comment: And sorry for being a bit confused I am new to shell-scripting :p

Comment: what is `open script`? Do you mean `run script`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
 printf "System: Now gathering power needed 1/3" 
 sh other_script
```

if other_script is in the same folder where you execute your main game.